# Serve root application instead of subfolder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

At work we have an ASP.NET MVC application with a 'Notifications' namespace and accompanying folder.

The problem comes when trying to access /notifications - IIS it tries to serve files out of the notifications folder, instead of invoking the site's default application.

This is not a problem when deploying because the code folders aren't deployed, but during development, IIS sees the folder and tries to serve it.

Does anybody know how to make it just serve the default ASP.NET application for the folder? The closest I got was setting up a virtual folder, but that doesn't work because of the web.config inheritance behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting the *notifications* folder as an application in IIS as opposed to a virtual directory?

Comment: It is neither a virtual folder or an application, and neither of those work. It is simply a folder in the root application.

Comment: So your instead of hitting your notifications controller it's actually hitting the physical folder on your hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only way to fix this is to rename either your folder or your controller. They can't be the same name because IIS looks inside of the folder **first**, and **then** if the folder **does not** exist, it goes to the ASP.NET ISAPI which then routes it to your controller.

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1781586.aspx?+Help+Controller+not+getting+hit

Sorry :(